# Making a minishell in C. How to improve error control with feoh and ferror?

Tags: c, error-handling

I've written this minishell but I'm not sure I'm making a correct control of the errors. Could you give me some advice?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdbool.h>

#define LINE_LEN  50
#define MAX_PARTS  50


int main ()
{
char* token;
char str[LINE_LEN];
char* arr[MAX_PARTS];
int i,j;
bool go_on = true;

while (go_on == true){
    printf("Write a line:('quit' to end) \n $:");
    fgets(str, LINE_LEN, stdin);

    if (str==NULL) {
        goto errorfgets;
    } else {
        size_t l=strlen(str);
        if(l && str[l-1]=='\n')
            str[l-1]=0;

        i=0;
        /* split string into words*/
        token = strtok(str, " \t\r\n");
        while( token != NULL ) 
        {
            arr[i] = token;
            i++;
            token = strtok(NULL," \t\r\n");
        }

        fflush(stdin);

        /* check if the first word is quit*/
        if (strcmp(arr[0],"quit")==0)
        {
            printf("Goodbye\n");
            go_on = false;
        } else {

            for (j=0; j < i; j++){
            printf("pajaritos por aqui'%s'\n", arr[j]);     
            }   
        }
    }
}

return 0;
errorfgets:
    printf("fgets didn't work correctly");
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I haven't really understood the point of your program but I'll try to give you a few hints :

- The indentation is not really good. I am not sure if this is because of SE but I'd rather point it out just in case.
- You'll hear everything and its opposite about `goto`. It surely has drawbacks but it can be quite useful to handle errors and free the ressources that are not required anymore. However, in your case, there's no need for `goto` so it's probably better to [Keep It Simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and just use `return`.
- I am not a big fan of a `go_on` variable if `break` can do the trick. Also, it makes `stdbool` pointless.
- Things will be easier to understand if you declare local variables in the smallest possible scope. Depending on the version of C you are using, you can even declare `j` in your `for` statement :  `for (int j=0; j < i; j++)`.
- Because of `return`/`break`, you can now remove levels of indentation (again, this is purely personal preference).
- You shouldn't repeat `"quit"` in multiple places. It will make it hard to change if it has to change in the future.
- There is a risk that `arr[i] = token;` goes to far if you ever change a constant without changing the other. Let's make sure it does not go too far.

At the end, here what the code would be like :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINE_LEN  50
#define MAX_PARTS  50

static const char quit[] = "quit";

int main ()
{
    char str[LINE_LEN];
    char* arr[MAX_PARTS];

    for (;;) {
        printf("Write a line:('%s' to end) \n $:", quit);
        fgets(str, LINE_LEN, stdin);

        if (str==NULL) {
            printf("fgets didn't work correctly");
            return -1;
        }
        size_t l = strlen(str);
        if (l && str[l-1]=='\n')
            str[l-1]=0;

        /* split string into words*/
        int i;
        char* token = strtok(str, " \t\r\n");
        for (i=0; i<MAX_PARTS && token != NULL; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL," \t\r\n");
        }

        fflush(stdin);

        /* check if the first word is quit*/
        if (strcmp(arr[0], quit)==0)
        {
            printf("Goodbye\n");
            break;
        }
        for (int j=0; j < i; j++){
            printf("pajaritos por aqui '%s'\n", arr[j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest following:

1. A separate error handler function. Don't exit from shell until user wants to. (most of shells do this)
2. `fgets()` is dangerous function (from compiler warnings). you could look into some system level functions to replicate `getch()` which gets a character and doesn't prints on screen and doesn't require a `return` for getting the character. It just get the character when you press the key. This way you can have a long input.(you have to print the characters manually if you use `getch()`)
3. Break down the loop into functions.
4. If you go for `getch()` you could even have shortcuts also.(not necessary as its a mini shell).
5. `getch()` can be helpful in getting the passwords as well.